# encryption/decryption & java - basic questions

Tags: java, encryption

I have to implement the following scenario.

User calls a webservice sending a request with a text which must be encrypted by my service if it isn't encrypted. After that it should be stored in the database. Is it a good idea to declare this attribute in xsd as String or is it a better type? Should I allow to use CDATA?

Using Jaxb I will convert this xml to a class with password stored in String object. Is it ok assuming that String is unicode (2 bytes)?

I have to use API which is a wraper for RSA client with 2 methods:

- decryptInformation(String)
- encryptInformation(String)

In most cases encrypting methods take an array of bytes as a parameter... I'm wondering if it may cause any unexpected errors.

I've also seen that people use Base64 class to do the encoding and decoding. Should I use it before I store encrypted text in database? Could you please explain it to me in a simple way?

Answer (score 4):

**On the need of encoding**
With many encryption methods, the *ciphertext*, i.e. the encrypted form of a message is an **array of bytes**, i.e. if viewed as sequence of "characters"  the ciphertext could include any character between 0 and 255 (decimal) or $00 and $FF (hexadecimal).  Such a range of characters includes many non-printable characters, say "tab" or "eot", as well as characters with a code above 128, which interpretation may vary.
Furthermore, even discounting these non-printable or "non-ASCII" characters, **some characters in the ciphertext may be such that they "throw off" the interpretation of a possible format where the ciphertext is included** (as for example XML, as hinted in the question).

For this reason, ciphertext must often be ***encoded*** so that it can be printed or included in text-oriented containers.

All encoding (of binary to text-like format) result in using more space for the encoded form of the data. Base64 is a popular format because it is relatively compact.

Another possible encoding format is hexadecimal ("base 16") which takes twice the size as the original binary data. Hexadecimal is also simpler/easier to use since there is a direct mapping between any byte in the input and its two corresponding characters in the output.  (whereby Base64 uses 1.25 characters to encode one byte, leading to blocks of 3 input bytes for encoded bytes)

**On the need to "Escape" encoded data**
Once the cyphertext is encoded, it may still include characters susceptible of throwing-off the structure of the "outside" format where the ciphertext is included, and that is why, in the case of XML, you may want to "escape" this content as CDATA.  (This is not necessary with Hexadecimal, and may not be needed in Base64, depending on the two extra character used (Base64 uses 0 thru 9, A thru Z, a thru z and two extra characters, typically + and /, as well as =).

**On the need of storing data in database as Base64** (or other encoding)
People use Base64 (or similar encodings) to store data in databases for two distinct reasons:

- to introduce a [mild/weak] encryption, *for data which is readily in text form*.  It is a weak form of encryption, as someone may quickly identify the encoding.  Never the less it makes the data stored less "obvious".
- to store *data that is in binary form*, as TEXT.

Most DBMSes include data types that allow stroring sequences of bytes in binary format, and it would therefore not be necessary to use encoding and storage to a Text-type format.  However, there are many reasons why people may still choose to store as text:

- because the data is eventually handed-out/used as encoded text (no need encrypt at run time, just encrypt once when data is stored)
- to facilitate portability
- to make debugging easier

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong:

1) encrypted message is an array of bytes. 
2) In order to print it (or include it in xml we have to encode it. To do it we can use Base64.
3) Even if it is encoded with Base64 client should "escape" it in the xml <- What xsd type should be use for this element - xsd:base64Binary? Can I use String type and "escape" with CDATA?
4) If xsd:base64Binary is used, does it mean that unmarhalling of this attribute will return a java String or array of bytes?

Comment: 5) To save the password in db I should, encrypt -> encode with Base64 -> save in DB.
6) To read the password from db: retrieve -> decode with Base64 -> decrypt ?

Comment: @Kumar: 1) ok, 2) ok, 3) no need to escape Base64 in XML, actually [sorry, my response was aimed at being generic, hence the confusion],  4) JAXB and similar library will bind xsd:base64Binary to a byte[], so that's what you should expect, both ways, i.e. you supply byte[] it encodes -directly- as base64,  you supply xsd:base64Binary it decodes -directly- to byte[], not to a string containing base64.  5) Yes that would work.  Alternatively you could store as binary object and not require the Base64 encoding/decoding.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, here is the sequence you should implement:

1. Send the server's public key to the client
2. Make the client sign the password (returns `byte[]`)
3. Base64 encode the signed password (returns `String`)
4. Send the base64 string via your web-service (using `xsd:base64Binary`)
5. On the server, unmarshall (using JAXB) the password (returns the byte array)
6. Store a base64 encoded string, a hex string, or the byte array (in Lob).

Comment: Is it possible to use xsd:String instead of xsd:base64Binary. I would like to use CDATA to send encoded String. 

What do you mean by base64 String and point number 4. Is it a byte array after unmarshalling?

Comment: http://java.sun.com/webservices/docs/2.0/tutorial/doc/JAXBWorks4.html - a byte array

Comment: Thanks! 

Do you know if it is safe to use xsd:String with CDATA instead of xsd:base64Binary?

One more question. You said that the text should be Base64 encoded. Can I use Base64 class from apache.commons with this method:

 String encodeToString(byte[] pArray) 
          Encodes a byte[] containing binary data, into a String containing characters in the Base64 alphabet.

and copy this string to the xml?

Comment: Yes, Base64 from apache-commons is a good choice.
I think it is safe to use xsd:String. But try it, and if something arises, whistle.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your encryption method the encrypted string might contain random byte orders, including stuff that might confuse a XML parser - including stuff like `]]>` that's unlikely but possible. Additionally the encrypted stirng might contain NULL bytes orother non-visible characters which create trouble while passing the file along.

Base 64 encoding makes sure only "valid" characters end in the document so you should base 64 encode your encrypted text.